# PHP - Is there a decent way so that the calling of mkdir creates folders relative to the web root?

Tags: php

The directory and file structure is as follows:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded
C:\xampp\htdocs\testA.php // as follows

$userID = 's002';
$uploadFolder = '/PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR/uploaded/';
$userDir = $uploadFolder . $userID;
mkdir($userDir, 0700);
```

If I call testA.php, then the following folder will be created.

```
C:\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded\s002
```

However, the desired result should be the following:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR\uploaded\s002
```

I would like to know a decent method so that the mkdir creates folder relative to the root of the web

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\
or
C:\wamp\www
```

Then in the future, I don't have problems to move this application to a web hosting site.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

- Create a file with defines that's always included and where you `define` what's the server root (or whatever prefix) so that you prepend it to the directory.
- Use a relative directory to the script. The directory of the script can be obtained with `dirname(__FILE__)`.
- Use a relative path to the current directory. The current directory, if not changed, is usually the directory of the PHP script that was originally called (usually not a good option).
- Use `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` (not a very good option, you might want your application in a subdirectory, and whether this value is available depends on the web server).

Comment: I like `dirname(__FILE__)` best--clean and portable.  In 5.3 and up you can just use `__DIR__` instead: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Comment: Hello Artefacto,

I would like to adopt the dirname(__FILE__) solution. However, I still don't quite get the idea. Assume that my upload folder is always below the root directory and named as upload_folder. How to make the connection between the running script with dirname(__FILE___) and point to the upload_folder?

Comment: @q0987 Let's say you're writing a script in `root/inc/myscrypt.inc.php`. You can use `dirname(__FILE__).'/../../directory'` to go that a sibling directory of `root`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$uploadFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/PHP_Upload_Image_MKDIR/uploaded/';
```